# How to show Wordpress latest post on another website?

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs

I had a request from a client to show the latest post in their blog on the homepage of their site. What is the simplest way to show a snippet or full post from their blog in their main site?

Comment: You could just set up an RSS feed.

Comment: is your main site built in php, or is it a different language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer,

http://www.corvidworks.com/articles/wordpress-content-on-other-pages

Answer (score 1):

Use the wordpress blogs rss feed

```
http://domain/feed/
```

And parse it to get the latest entry